# jq: error (at <stdin>:131): Cannot iterate over string ("Files")

Tags: jq

I am trying to parse JSON and getting stuck when it comes to iterating over a array.

```
[
  {
    "severity": "low",
    "name": "AWS IAM policy attached to users",
    "rule": "$.resource[*].aws_iam_policy_attachment[*].*[*].users exists and $.resource[*].aws_iam_policy_attachment[*].*[*].users[*] is not empty",
    "files": [
      "main.tf"
    ],
    "id": "1903f355-b68f-4d9c-84dd-c46abe4f8673"
  },
  {
    "severity": "medium",
    "name": "AWS VPC allows unauthorized peering",
    "rule": "$.resource[*].aws_vpc_peering_connection[*].*[*].peer_vpc_id does not equal $.resource[*].aws_vpc_peering_connection[*].*[*].vpc_id",
    "files": [
      "vpcpeering.tf",
      "main.tf"
    ],
    "id": "59356130-d856-470d-a08e-b2a0ba2a4ac7"
  }
]
```

```
. += [{"severity": "Severity","name": "Name","files": "Files","id": "0"}, {"severity": "--------","name": "------------------------------------","files": "--------","id": "01"}] |  sort_by(.id) | .[] | ["| " + .severity, "| " + .name, "| " + (.files | join (",")) , "| " ]
```

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:131): Cannot iterate over string ("Files")
exit status 5
```

https://jqplay.org/s/KzNXa7NqKq

I am trying to print the results in tabular format.

```
Severity. Name.                                 Files
low       AWS IAM policy attached to users.     main.tf
low       AWS VPC allows unauthorized peering.  vpcpeering.tf, main.tf
```

Comment: The `files` property on the objects you added are not arrays, they're strings. You "cannot iterate over string", put them in arrays.

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  Can you simplify the input (while keeping it valid JSON)? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of items in the .files array is variable, the following will focus on producing TSV (tab-separated values).  You can easily adapt this solution to your requirements regarding a table with a variable number of columns.

First, ignoring the headers, note that the following filter, when used in conjunction with the -r command-line option, produces the output as shown:

```
map({id, severity, name, files})
| sort_by(.id)[]
| [.severity, .name, .files[]]
| @tsv
```

#### Output

```
low AWS IAM policy attached to users    main.tf
medium  AWS S3 object versioning is disabled    cloudtrail.tf.json  cloudtrail.tf
medium  AWS VPC NACL allows traffic from blocked ports  SG.tf
medium  AWS security group allow egress traffic from blocked ports - 21,22,135,137-139,445,69   securitygroup22.tf
medium  AWS Access logging not enabled on S3 buckets    cloudtrail.tf.json  cloudtrail.tf
medium  AWS VPC allows unauthorized peering vpcpeering.tf
medium  AWS IAM password policy does not have a minimum of 14 characters    iampassword.tf
medium  AWS security group allows traffic from blocked ports    securitygroup22.tf
high    AWS Security Groups allow internet traffic to SSH port (22) securitygroup22.tf
medium  AWS EC2 instance have SSH port open to internet securitygroup22.tf
medium  AWS IAM password policy allows password reuse   iampassword.tf
medium  AWS VPC NACL allow egress traffic from blocked ports    SG.tf
high    AWS Security Groups with Inbound rule overly permissive to All Traffic  securitygroup22.tf
```

### Headers

A modular way to deal with the header row is to define `headers`, e.g. along these lines:

```
def headers:
  ["Severity","Name","Files"],
  ["--------","----","-----"] ;
```

With this def, we essentially just add `headers` to the previous jq program:

```
headers,
(map({id, severity, name, files})
 | sort_by(.id)[]
 | [.severity, .name, .files[]])
| @tsv
```

### Using a different "join" character for .files

Instead of the line:
    [.severity, .name, .files[]]

you might wish to use a different "join" character for the files, e.g.

```
[.severity, .name, (.files|join(";"))]
```

Season to taste.

Comment: See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57222/how-can-i-use-column-to-delimit-on-tabs-and-not-spaces

Comment: How can i add headers to the output?

Comment: That’s already covered somewhat in the posted answer, so you’ll need to be more specific about your requirements.

Comment: Sorry missed the header part. Will try it now.

Comment: [Update}: It worked like a charm. Thank you so much!!